# Java card game. How to call in main

Tags: java, arrays, object, histogram

The purpose of this program is to create a deck of cards and the methods' names are self explanatory.  I think I have all the methods correct, but I need to test them all in main and I'm not sure how.  I am new to objects, arrays, and histograms.  Any examples on how to test some of the array/histogram methods would be helpful.  Just trying to learn and understand. Thank you!

For example, one of the methods I want to test is printDeck.  So in main, I type "printDeck(deck);"  but it needs to know where to get deck and I'm confused on how to do that.

```
class Cards {
int suit, rank;


public Cards() {
    this.suit = 0;
    this.rank = 1;
}


public Cards(int suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}

public static int compareCard (Cards c1, Cards c2) {
    if (c1.suit>c2.suit) return 1;
    else if (c1.suit<c2.suit) return-1;
    else {
        if (c1.rank == 1)c1.rank = 14; 
        if (c2.rank == 1)c2.rank = 14;
        if (c1.rank>c2.rank) {
            if (c1.rank == 14)c1.rank = 1;
            return 1;
        } else if (c1.rank<c2.rank) {
            if (c2.rank == 14)c2.rank = 1;
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (c1.rank == 14)c1.rank = 1;
            if (c2.rank == 14)c2.rank = 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


public static void buildDeck () {
    Cards[] deck = new Cards[52];
    int i = 0;
    for (int s = 0; s<4; s++) {
        for (int r = 1; r<14; r++) {
            deck[i] = new Cards(s, r);
            i++;
        }
    }
}


public static int handScore (Cards[] ar) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i =0; i< ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i].rank > 10) x += (ar[i].rank-10);
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i =0; i< ar.length; i++) {
        result += ar[i].rank;
    }
    return result-x;
}


public static Cards parseCard(String s) {
    Cards emptyCard = null;
    String[] suits = {" ", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    String[] ranks = {"n", "Ace", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    String sr = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' '));
    String ss = s.substring (s.lastIndexOf(' ')+1, s.length()-1);
    int holdRank = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<ranks.length; i++) {
        if (ranks[i].equals(sr)) holdRank = i;
    }
    if (holdRank == 0) return emptyCard;
    int holdSuit = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<suits.length; i++) {
        if (ranks[i].equals(sr)) holdSuit = i;
    }
    if (holdSuit == 0)return emptyCard;
    Cards result = new Cards (holdSuit-1, holdRank);
    return result;
}

public static int[] suitHist (Cards[] ar) {
    int[] hist = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i<ar.length; i++) {
        hist[ar[i].suit]++;
    }
    return hist;
}


public static boolean isFlush (Cards[] ar) {
    int[] h = suitHist(ar);
    if (h[0] > 4 || h[1] > 4 || h[2] > 4|| h[3] > 4) return true;
    else return false;
}


public static void printCard (Cards c) {
 String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
 String[] ranks = { "narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
 "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
 System.out.println (ranks[c.rank] + " of " + suits[c.suit]);
} 

public static void printDeck (Cards[] deck) {
 for (int i=0; i<deck.length; i++) {
 printCard (deck[i]);
 }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

Comment: Since they are all static methods, just call them with the parameters they need to be passed from main.

Comment: downvoter, please explain

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question. The OP is seeking information to connect to ideas.

Comment: @jace, I didn't downvote, so I cannot speak for the person who did, but it was likely downvoted because it is a very basic/beginner question that is likely from a homework problem which means the information for it is probably contained within class notes and project/homework specifications, and additionally, it is likely the goal of the instructor for the students to figure this out on their own. However, I personally do not see a huge problem with the question so long as the OP learns from the answer. I just know that I have been downvoted before for such questions when I was learning.

Comment: nah. i'm not against the downvote :) just leave a comment if you do. just for a practice. It can also be closed because it is primarily opinion based. I just asked for explanation so the OP will know :)

Comment: @jace How is it opinion based?

Comment: @cricket_007 let me delete the opinion based statement. As it differs to what I meant when I searched for "opinion" meaning :D my apology. But anyway, I just hate those who downvote without leaving there reason. We are all here for learnings. OP is seeking for it. Some questions maybe basic for some, but big deal for others. Let's just help each other :)

Comment: @jace: Voting is anonymous on SO for a reason. If you want to know why, spend some time on [meta] and [meta.se], where it has been explained (and discussed) in depth. Comments are not required when voting in either direction. If the voter chooses to leave one or not is entirely within their discretion. Requiring a comment would no longer be anonymous, as a comment has the name of the commenter attached. You should review the [help] pages to learn how this site works. (Not a voter of any sort here; just happened to see your comment.)

Comment: @KenWhite I don't want some argument with others, so if that it should be, then i'm out with it :) . It's fine, maybe it's just a matter of perspective :).

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I'm sorry for asking such a beginner question, but I am just trying to learn.  It might seem stupid to some of you, but @cricket_007 really helped me understand how to call objects and I can now apply that to my other methods.  I have gotten my feelings hurt multiple times by people hating the fact that my questions aren't super difficult.  We need to accept that we are all on different levels of our coding journeys. Thank you to those who helped. :)

Comment: Feel free to go over the official Java tutorials on Oracle site to get a better grasp

Comment: @jace: My point was that downvoters are not required to comment. If they choose to do so, they will. If they did not, then it's useless to ask them to do it, because they've already voted and moved on. Posting useless comment clutter is not going to help anyone. It just adds noise. You should learn how the site works.

Comment: Lauren, your question was fine. It at least showed a real effort to do things yourself, and you explained the problem you were having.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you. :)

Comment: @KenWhite i'm not forcing anyone even it has a please ... just the same with the stackoverflow message "please consider leaving a comment ..." when you downvote. I just hate those who don't because others will just down vote it because someone started downvoting without giving their reason. But I do not require it because nobody can require anyone here. My point is, Leaving reason can help others to avoid repeating their mistake (just the same way I learned)

Comment: anyway, the OP already have the answer. Let's now end this in here :) sorry OP for this small argument in your comment box :) Happy for you that you learned something :)

Comment: @jace No need to apologize, all is well! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I have all the methods correct,

Not quite...

Your method to build a deck should actually give you a built deck.

```
public static Card[] buildDeck ()  {
   ... 
    return deck;
}
```

That should help you to get a deck in main.

```
Card[] cards = buildDeck();
printDeck(cards);
```

---

The proper way to test your programs, though would generally be unit tests, not the main method

Comment: Thank you.  Now when I go to print the deck in main, I type "System.out.println(buildDeck());" and the output is "[LCards;@15db9742".  How do I get it to actually print the deck of cards?

Comment: Did you write this code? You have `printDeck`, so use that

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry I am flustered.  I meant to type "System.out.println(printDeck(deck));" and then ask how to define the variable deck and what to define it as.

Comment: One cannot print a void method. If you are using an IDE, that much would be an error. Please see updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience!!  I think I get the gist  now.  Very helpful. :)